# How to fake out a subdomain lookup in Rails tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, functional-testing

I have the following filter defined:

```
# application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :find_account

  private

    def find_account
      @current_account = Account.find_by_subdomain!(request.subdomains.first)
    end
end
```

and in my test:

```
# users_controller_test.rb
class UsersControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  setup do
    @request.host = "test.myapp.local"
  end
  # ...
end
```

Now `test` is defined as the subdomain for a dummy account that I load prior to all requests using `factory_girl`.  However, this is throwing a nil object error, saying that @request is nil.  Removing the setup block causes all of my tests to fail as find_account cannot find an account and therefore throws a `RecordNotFound` error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've got the same problem, did you find a solution?

Comment: Useful to find that you are using request.subdomains to get subdomain, I used to get it from params[:subdomain] but it does not work if I set @request.host or @request.env['HTTP_HOST']

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
@request.env['HTTP_HOST'] = 'test.myapp.local'
```